# Emacs Italic Org-mode

Tags: emacs, fonts, org-mode

I'm having troubles with the fonts. I think emacs is not displaying the italic font. I notice this mainly when I'm using org-mode, because the italics characters are not appearing.

[image: Font Test in Org-mode]

As you can see in the image above, the **second line** should appear in italic, and I don't know why it's not doing it. I'm quite sure it was working at some point before. I was playing around with the font customization, but I didn't succeed.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Does the font you use supply an italic variant?

Comment: As I said, I was seeing that before, and I didn't change fonts. When I do ==M-x describe-font== I get name (opened by): -unknown-Droid Sans Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-15-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
       full name: Droid Sans Mono:pixelsize=15:foundry=unknown:weight=normal:slant=normal:width=normal:spacing=100:scalable=true
            size: 15
          height: 18
 baseline-offset:  0
relative-compose:  0

Comment: @choroba, do you have any idea how to test the fonts fast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@choroba was totally right about the font. I just changed it.

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist
                       '(font . "DejaVu Sans Mono-11"))
```

As a note, you can play around with the font with `S-left_click`